# Accessing cells in another workbook fails

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook called "C:\myfile.xlsm".

It has a worksheet called "sales".

From within another open workbook I am trying to access a cell value from that C:\myfile.xlsm workbook.

(BTW: C:\myfile.xlsm is NOT open.)

Doing the following fails:

```
temp = Workbooks("C:\myfile.xlsm").Worksheets("sales").Range("C2").Value
```

I get this error and I don't know why:

> Run time error 9
>
> Subscript out of range

Comment: You don't actually *ask* a question, you know. All the Answers infer that you want to know WHY you're getting the error and how to use the code you show. It's a bit unfair of you to reply to these answers that your problem has to do with the speed involved and that you're trying to find a way to not open the workbook! That said, search for information on connecting to the workbook using OLE DB (a database connection). If the workbook content you want to query is in "flat table" format or the key information is in named ranges, that should be more efficient that actually opening the workbook.

Comment: The OLE DB worked like a charm. Quite fast, too. I ran it in a new workbook that accesses an existing workbook with over 80,000 rows. The initial setup took time because that spreadsheet has a dozen worksheets. One contains those 80,000 rows. Others have many thousands more. But once I selected on that one needed workbook and saved the new workbook, I can restart the latter and pull in an update in just five seconds. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hopefully it helps you too ?

```
Private Sub stuff()
    Dim TemP As String
    TemP = "C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\doug" & "\" & "Book1.xlsm"
    Set TemP2 = Workbooks.Open(TemP)
    Temp3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("e1").Value
    Debug.Print ; Temp3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need fist open then file.

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\myfile.xlsm"
```

After you can use the file

```
temp = Workbooks("myfile.xlsm").Worksheets("sales").Range("C2").Value
```

If you want get the value only:

```
temp = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:[myfile.xlsm]Sales'!" & Range("C2").Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))
```

Comment: I was hoping **NOT** to have to open the file. It's very large and it's slow to open.

I am able to access cells from that workbook **without** opening it.
But that's by putting appropriate formulas into cells of a worksheet.
Something like:

    ='C:\[file.xlsm]sales'!C2

But I really want to do things in VBA, and I don't want to have to wait for the targeted workbook to open.

Is there a way?

Comment: You can use the ExecuteExcel4Macro:
temp = ExecuteExcel4Macro("'C:\[myfile.xlsm]Sales'!" & Range("C2").Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1))

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
Set wk = Workbooks.Open("C:\myfile.xlsm")
temp = wk.Sheets("sales").Range("C2").Value
wk.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting Cell Value from different workbook without opening it try this:

```
Sub Demo()        
    Dim Path As String, FileName As String, SheetName As String, CellRange As String
    Dim tempStr As String
    Path = "C:\"
    FileName = "myfile.xlsm"
    SheetName = "Sales"
    CellRange = Range("C2").Address(, , xlR1C1)

    strRef = "'" & Path & "[" & FileName & "]" & SheetName & "'!" & CellRange

    Result = ExecuteExcel4Macro(strRef)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mrig. That should be just what I need. I'm off now to give it a try.

Comment: OK. Tried it. It works. But, unfortunately, it's very slow. My original question was seeking to copy just one cell. In the full solution, though, I have to pull around 6000 rows, each with 7 cells. IT'S REALLY SLOW! :(